# Accessing an attribute from container class

Tags: java, swing

I have an A class and a B class

In the A class I have multiple B instances. From A class, after defining B, I write a mouseListener event for the B class, and it works. Now I realiced that I have to write the same mouseListener for every B class that I instantiate, and all they do is the same: Opening a DialogBox asking for a number, so I decided to write that mouseListener in the B class constructor.

The problem comes when that mouseListener has to access to an A's private attribute. In this point, I thought about using a functional interface / callback to send values from B to A when the mouseEvent is fired, but I feel like the code will be a little bit messy, like I'm using the wrong tools to reach the functionality I want, maybe I'm wrong...

Any advice or recomendation ? I'll post a little bit of the code so you can understand it better. This is my A class: This code works but now think that I have to write the same code lines again and again

PowerConfigPanel is the A class.
PTextField is the B class.
connectionListener is the A private attribute I was talking about.

```
public class PowerConfigPanel extends JPanel {

    private ConnectionListener connectionListener;

    public PowerConfigPanel(){
        PTextField SUSPEND_CHARGER_BF= new PTextField(7);
        SUSPEND_CHARGER_BF.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseClicked(e);
                JPanel insertValuePanel = new JPanel();
                insertValuePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2,1,1));
                PTextField field = new PTextField(7);
                insertValuePanel.add(UtilsService.createComponentPanel(field,"Insert Value "));

                int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, insertValuePanel,
                        "Please Enter a new Value", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

                if(result  == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input for seconds", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    connectionListener.connect("a","b",Integer.valueOf(field.getText()));
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

What I mean is: mouseClick returns void... is there any possibility to make it return an integer and collect that integer in the A class when the B class is clicked?

Comment: Why not pass `connectionListener` to `PTextField` constructor?

Comment: Because PTextField shouldn't know anything about connectionListener, my A class should handle that or atleast is the design I want to follow @Oleg

Comment: Then the only option to "return" from `mouseClicked` to `A` is with a callback.

Comment: Yeah... I'm implementing a callback now, but I wanted to ask anyways to see if anyone had a better idea. @Oleg